# How do I interpret the weapon damage stat in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

In Borderlands when looking at the damage of weapons, particularly shotguns, it says stuff like 20x6.  Does that mean the true damage is 120?  Is there something special that must occur for you to get the times 6?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

the 20x6 simply means each shot has 6 bullets, which has a spread.  If all 6 of your fragments hit the target, then the damage will be 120, or more/less depending on critical, level difference etc.

On some guns, like the Wave, the rounds come out parallel to each other, making this significantly harder to hit with all your shots.

Comment: Also, check out [Borderlands Wikia](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Borderlands_Wiki) there are some charts, etc there that go into detail on DPS, etc.